# Rabbitmq with STOMP refuses connection from browser

Tags: java, angular, docker, rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq Docker with the stomp plugin enabled.
Whenever I try to establish a connection to the docker I receive the following error:
`STOMP connection 172.19.0.1:54578 -> 172.19.0.2:61613 terminated with reason {shutdown,                                                                             login_timeout}, closing it.`

The rabbitmq config is set as below:

```
loopback_users = none
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
default_pass = guest
default_user = guest
hipe_compile = false
management.listener.port = 15672
management.listener.ssl = false
stomp.listeners.tcp.1 = 61613
stomp.default_user = guest
stomp.default_pass = guest
```

The front end is set up with RxStomp as follows:

```
import { RxStompConfig } from '@stomp/rx-stomp';

export const myRxStompConfig: RxStompConfig = {
    // Which server?
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:61613/topic/',

    // Headers
    // Typical keys: login, passcode, host
    connectHeaders: {
       login: 'guest',
       passcode: 'guest',
    },
}
```

Backend

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketMessageBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer 
{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```